# Difference between P4.net and P4api.net

Tags: perforce, p4.net, p4api.net

What is the exact difference between p4.net and p4api.net?

I was trying to create a custom gui based tool for perforce and I started developing it using p4api.net. Much later I came to know about the existence of p4.net. Now I am confused with their difference and the purpose.

Also I have a doubt on which option to choose for the development.

Is there something else other than these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P4API.NET is the supported API for .NET applications, so I'd go with that.  You can see a list of the officially released APIs for the various languages [here](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/apis).